# Do CUDA device IDs change when debugging?

Tags: cuda

I've noticed that, on a host with two working CUDA SM_2.x devices, the first of which is running the display, calling cudaSetDevice(1) in the debugger throws CUDA error 10 (invalid device). It works fine when executed outside of the debugger, however. I also note that the device which normally has ID 1 has device ID 0 inside the debugger.

Are my suspicions confirmed that device ID 0 is assigned only to the first *available* device, rather than the device installed in the first PCIe slot?

If so, is there a way of ensuring that e.g. cudaSetDevice(1) always selects the same device, irrespective of how CUDA assigns device IDs?

Comment: Which OS/platform?  Which debugger?

Comment: Fedora 23 Linux, cuda-gdb. Do different debuggers and OS have different behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The really short answer is, no, there is no way to do this. Having said that, hardcoding a fixed device id is never the correct thing to do. You want to either:

1. Select an id from the list of available devices which the API returns for you (and there are a number of very helpful APIs to let you get the device you want), or
2. You don't use *any* explicit device selection at all in your code and rely on appropriate driver compute mode settings and/or the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`  environment setting to have the driver automatically select a suitable valid device ID for you.

Which you choose will probably dictated by the environment in which your code ends up being deployed.

Comment: This is an issue, since we use code-generation and our own occupancy optimisation code to fix chosen devices and block sizes after a dry-run compile. Getting back to my original question, is there a way to guarantee that the chosen device is always used?

Comment: @JamesTurner: Yes, use either method in my answer. You need to be more sophisticated in the way you chose devices, not try and bend the runtime device enumeration to your will. The device enumeration is not guaranteed to be fixed and trying to assume it is a broken approach, as you are discovering.

Comment: The reason I ask of this is because our software generates code which will run on specific heterogeneous compute cluster configurations - i.e. mixed device architecture on the same node - according to our *own* load balancing algorithms, not someone elses. Model graph partitioning is performed before code generation, so we cannot rely on all these very helpful APIs at runtime, unfortunately. I wouldn't call asking the runtime to give me the device I need it to give me "bending the runtime to my will". Perhaps this is a feature which should be added, if it isn't already there.

Comment: @JamesTurner: But you can get the *device* you want at runtime, in a controllable, repeatable, universal fashion. But you can't assume it will be enumerated as device 1 every time. There is a subtle but important difference between the two.

Comment: Okay, I believe I have found a mechanism which achieves what you are talking about: cudaDeviceGetByPCIBusId and cudaDeviceGetPCIBusId. So a solution more robust than I currently have would be to not use cudaSetDevice, and instead set device using PCIe bus ID directly.

Comment: @JamesTurner: Exactly. The runtime will get you the device ID of the device you want, then you use that ID. I have had things as simple as a kernel patch change PCI-e device discovery order on a multi-GPU node, resulting the the CUDA driver enumerating devices in a different order. It might sound like extra work, but it is the only way to do this safely.